# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space still exist

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat

i debug a project through tomcat in eclipse,a error throw like:
[image]
[image]
[image]
and the eclipse is not unresponsive,the error report like

> Daemon System Thread [Java2D Disposer] (Suspended (exception
>   OutOfMemoryError))        owns: Win32GraphicsEnvironment  (id=116)        owns:
>   FontStrikeDisposer  (id=117)      D3DGraphicsDevice.getDeviceCaps(int)
>   line: 108     D3DGraphicsDevice.createDevice(int) line: 87
>     Win32GraphicsEnvironment.makeScreenDevice(int) line: 208
>     Win32GraphicsEnvironment(SunGraphicsEnvironment).getScreenDevices()
>   line: 139     Win32GraphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice() line:
>   96        StrikeCache.disposeStrike(FontStrikeDisposer) line: 284 
>     FontStrikeDisposer.dispose() line: 98

when i debug again,the error report like

> 严重: Servlet.service() for servlet [springDispatcher] in context with
>   path [/api] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested
>   exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space] with root
>   cause java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:144)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:41)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:55)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:169)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:149)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.get(DefaultHashOperations.java:44)
>     at
>   com.unistrong.tracker.service.cache.UserCache.getUserToken(UserCache.java:31)
>     at
>   com.unistrong.tracker.handle.UserHandle.saveLogon(UserHandle.java:439)
>     at
>   com.unistrong.tracker.web.UserController.logon(UserController.java:98)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>
> Exception in thread "Java2D Disposer"

i have change eclipse.ini and tomcat to enlarge memory,but the error still exists
[image]
[image]

how to solve the problem? thanks for you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to increase the PermGen size by java command argument:**

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=128M
```

Comment: thanks,i found the reference http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.stardust.docs.wst%2Fhtml%2Fwst-integration%2Fconfiguration.html